# subview location after UIView Rotation

Tags: iphone

I have UIView which have subviews , I have rotated view with 90.

```
CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(degreesToRadians(degrees));
```

Now I need to subview location in screen coordinate system and for that I am doing

```
CGPoint subViewPoint = [[subView superview]  convertPoint:subView.frame.origin toView:baseView];
```

This is working fine , if I am not rotating the View but its not working if i am rotating the view. Please help me on this.

How to get the subview location in screen after its super view 90 rotation.

Comment: Base view is UIView this baseview has subview

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but there are two things to know.

1) You should avoid using *frame* property when you have to deal with transformations. Use *center* and *bounds* properties instead. Frames of views that have not identity transformations are invalid.

2) You can always use CGPointApplyAffineTransform function to calculate point coordinates by yourself : )

Hope this'll help.